# Error: import org.exist.xmldb.XQueryService cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, xquery, exist-db, xbrl

I have imported a project related to xbrl api with oracle berkely db, it has import `org.exist.xmldb.XQueryService` but the dependency is missing.

I have added the `exist-xmldb-0.9.2` jar but still unable to resolve.

What is the **maven** dependency I need to add to resolve this?

Comment: What are you asking? There's no question in this post.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/exist/exist-xmldb/0.9.2?

Comment: 2005 when that repo last updated